# How to populate Combobox with result of Powershell command

Tags: list, powershell, combobox, get

Can someone assist on how to fill a combobox with the result of a powershell command?

Im trying to fill a combobox with the result of a "Get" cmdlet but I only get some powershell parameters as result.

```
$ButtonCollectionSearch.Add_Click({
    $name = $textboxlogonname.text
    $ComboBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $ComboBox.Width = 400
    $Collections = Get-RDSessionCollection | fl  -Property CollectionName

    Foreach ($Collection in $Collection) {
        $ComboBox.Items.Add($Collection);
    }
    $ComboBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(120, 10)
    $main_form.Controls.Add($ComboBox)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Change `... |fl  -Property CollectionName` to `... |Select-Object -Property CollectionName`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting formatting metadata is that you *asked* for formatting metadata - by piping all your data through `fl` (which is a alias for `Format-List`).

Since we just want the value of the `CollectionName`, use `ForEach-Object -MemberName` in place of `fl -Property`:

```
$Collections = Get-RDSessionCollection | ForEach-Object -MemberName CollectionName
```

You'll also want to address the typo in the `foreach` loop declaration - change:

```
Foreach ($Collection in $Collection) {
```

to:

```
Foreach ($Collection in $Collections) {
```